How to avoid "! Package tagpdf Error: The number of automatic begin (3) and end (2)" when using box concept in LuaLaTeX
I am facing the error: "Package tagpdf Error: The number of automatic begin (3) and end (2)" when using a box concept with an accessibility PDF. Please advise how to solve this case. My MWE is below.
Compiler: lualatex-dev.exe (2024)
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table,pdfversion = 2.0}}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\newbox\footbox%
\newdimen\footboxht%

\newcommand\openerinfo{%
    \global\setbox\footbox=\vbox{\noindent\printtitle}%
    \footboxht=\ht\footbox%
    \ifdim\footboxht>10pt%
        {\small\unvbox\footbox\par}%
    \else%
        {\Large\unvbox\footbox\par}%
    \fi%
    \addvspace{40pt}%
}

\gdef\printtitle{}
\def\temptitle#1{\gdef\printtitle{#1}}

\makeatother


\temptitle{Title of the article the first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book.}

\openerinfo

The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book, in which only terms and notions familiar from traditional grammar and/or introductory courses in morphosyntax are used. Section 1.2 discusses the position taken by the author about some concepts generally considered basic for the analysis of clause structure and its semantic correlates, and the terms used to refer to them. Section 1.3 presents the framework within which transitivity, valency, Opener Page Footnote text and voice are discussed in the remainder of the book.

\end{document}

Error message:


Use \par before closing the box, but what is the intention here, the font size commands will have no effect on unboxed material
